# Apply Horizontal Scrolling to SharePoint List

Tags: javascript

I want to apply horizontal scrolling to SharePoint Discussion Board but I don't have sufficient scripting knowledge on how to do it.

Please help me with some link that can guide me with this.

Comment: Check this one-
http://kyleschaeffer.com/sharepoint/sharepoint-2010-scrolling/